# Ruby Rails: Form application routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-examples.htm). It has written in previous version of Rails and I am using Rails 4. In section "Creating view file for new method" I have updated given code sample to work with current Rails but I am getting following error:

```
SystemStackError in BookController#create
stack level too deep

Rails.root: C:/Ruby193/mylibrary

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"Xla1xJlMqCx96ZITbI6JHOvoNIoAHc5ItcZgcMzs0/Y=",
 "title"=>"MyBook",
 "price"=>"15",
 "book"=>{"subject_id"=>"1"},
 "description"=>"fine",
 "commit"=>"Create",
 "class"=>"nifty_form",
 "method"=>"post"}
Toggle session dump
Toggle env dump
Response

Headers:

None
```

Here is my routing file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
get 'book/list' => 'book#list'
get 'book/new' => 'book#new'
post 'book/create' => 'book#create'
end
```

Here is my controller class:

```
class BookController < ApplicationController
   def list
      @books = Book.all
   end
   def show
      @book = Book.find(params[:id])
   end
   def new
      @book = Book.new
      @subjects = Subject.all
   end
   def create
      @book = Book.new(params[:book])
      if @book.save
        redirect_to :action => 'list'
      else
        @subjects = Subject.all
        render :action => 'new'
      end
   end
   def edit
      @book = Book.find(params[:id])
      @subjects = Subject.all
   end
   def update
      @book = Book.find(params[:id])
      if @book.update_attributes(params[:book])
         redirect_to :action => 'show', :id => @book
      else
         @subjects = Subject.all
         render :action => 'edit'
      end
   end
   def delete
      Book.find(params[:id]).destroy
      redirect_to :action => 'list'
   end

   private
   def params
     params.require(:book).permit(:title, :price, :description)
   end

end
```

Here is my new.html

```
<h1>Add new book</h1>
<%= form_tag(controller: "book", action: "create", method: "post", class: "nifty_form") do %>

<%= label_tag(:title, "Title") %>
<%= text_field_tag(:title) %><br>
<%= label_tag(:price, "Price") %>
<%= text_field_tag(:price) %><br>
<%= label_tag(:q, "Subject") %>
<%= collection_select(:book,:subject_id,@subjects,:id,:name) %><br>
<%= label_tag(:description, "Description") %><br>
<%= text_area_tag(:description) %><br>
<%= submit_tag( "Create") %>

<%end %>
<%= link_to 'Back', {:action => 'list'} %>
```

What should I do?

UPDATE-1:

I have updated my controller as suggested in comments:

```
class BookController < ApplicationController
   def list
      @books = Book.all
   end
   def show
      @book = Book.find(params[:id])
   end
   def new
      @book = Book.new
      @subjects = Subject.all
   end
   def create
      @book = Book.new(book_params)
      if @book.save!
        redirect_to :action => 'list'
      else
        @subjects = Subject.all 
        render :action => 'new'
      end
   end
   def edit
      @book = Book.find(params[:id])
      @subjects = Subject.all
   end
   def update
      @book = Book.find(params[:id])
      if @book.update_attributes(book_params)
         redirect_to :action => 'show', :id => @book
      else
         @subjects = Subject.all
         render :action => 'edit'
      end
   end
   def delete
      Book.find(params[:id]).destroy
      redirect_to :action => 'list'
   end

   private

   def book_params
     params.require(:book).permit(:title, :price, :description)
   end

end
```

Now I am getting following error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid in BookController#create
Validation failed: Title can't be blank, Price Error Message

Extracted source (around line #14):
12
13
14
15
16
17

  def create
    @book = Book.new(book_params)
    if @book.save!
      redirect_to :action => 'list'
    else
      @subjects = Subject.all

Rails.root: C:/Ruby193/mylibrary

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/book_controller.rb:14:in `create'
Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"Xla1xJlMqCx96ZITbI6JHOvoNIoAHc5ItcZgcMzs0/Y=",
 "title"=>"asd",
 "price"=>"asd",
 "book"=>{"subject_id"=>"1"},
 "description"=>"asd",
 "commit"=>"Create",
 "method"=>"post"}
Toggle session dump
Toggle env dump
Response

Headers:

None
```

Comment: Why you have this `@subjects = Subject.all` in `else` part of `create`.It is already there in `new` method.

Comment: I am not sure, I tried to remove it but, it made no diferrence.

Comment: You are using `Rails 4` and you are not using `strong parameters`.I guess it is the error.

Comment: change `def params` to `def some_params` , and your action `create` you just call `@book = Book.new(some_params)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `Rails 4` and you are not using `strong parameters` in your `controller code`.I guess it is the error.

Try changing your controller code to like this

```
class BookController < ApplicationController
   def list
      @books = Book.all
   end
   def show
      @book = Book.find(params[:id])
   end
   def new
      @book = Book.new
      @subjects = Subject.all
   end
   def create
      @book = Book.new(book_params)
      if @book.save
        redirect_to :action => 'list'
      else
        @subjects = Subject.all 
        render :action => 'new'
      end
   end
   def edit
      @book = Book.find(params[:id])
      @subjects = Subject.all
   end
   def update
      @book = Book.find(params[:id])
      if @book.update_attributes(book_params)
         redirect_to :action => 'show', :id => @book
      else
         @subjects = Subject.all
         render :action => 'edit'
      end
   end
   def delete
      Book.find(params[:id]).destroy
      redirect_to :action => 'list'
   end

   private

   def book_params
     params.require(:book).permit(:title, :price, :description)
   end

end
```

**Note:** You are following a very old Tutorial.I recommend these **[Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/)**.

Comment: I think this `@subjects = Subject.all` need to define again when `@book` not save, because in form will call variable `@subjects` on `create` action not `new` action.

Comment: @anonymousxxx Nice catch! Updated :)

Comment: Thank you very munch, I have tried your answer and when I click create button it doesnt save the book and returns the form again. What sould we do next?

Comment: @Mukaddes Try giving `if @book.save!` You might have some `validation errors`

Comment: I have tried `if @book.save!` now I am getting `Validation failed: Title can't be blank, Price Error Message`error

Comment: @Mukaddes Make sure those validations are met.

Comment: I am sure that they are not blank. HEre is the parameters I sent in error page: `{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"Xla1xJlMqCx96ZITbI6JHOvoNIoAHc5ItcZgcMzs0/Y=",
 "title"=>"afs",
 "price"=>"67",
 "book"=>{"subject_id"=>"1"},
 "description"=>"gsgfs",
 "commit"=>"Create",
 "method"=>"post"}` How can I validate them?

Comment: @Mukaddes Seems weird.Try posting a different question explaining the problem in detail.For now it is the solution for your current question.

Comment: @Mukaddes I mean not here in this question.Post it as separate post.